# How to use GlobalContext in ModelRoute?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a global navigator key used in materialApp

```
navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

```
MaterialApp(  navigatorKey: Utils.navigatorKeyy,
```

I am using this like:

```
while (
    ModalRoute.of(Utils.navigatorKey.currentState!.context)!
        .settings
        .name ==
        '/booking/hotelDetail' &&  Navigator.of(context).canPop()
      ) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

this returns null always

```
ModalRoute.of(Utils.navigatorKey.currentState!.context)
```

How to use a global context to get current route name?

Comment: ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name   giving only the particular widget's route name, even that was popped

Answer (score 0):

**Create a static method in a class that holds the navigator key and pass the context as an argument:**

```
class NavigationService {
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  static String getCurrentRouteName(BuildContext context) {
    final ModalRoute<dynamic>? route = ModalRoute.of(context);
    return route?.settings.name ?? '';
  }
}
```

**Use NavigationService.getCurrentRouteName(context) to get the current route name**

```
if (NavigationService.getCurrentRouteName(context) == '/booking/hotelDetail' && Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

**Initialize the navigator key in the**

> MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
  navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigatorKey,
  // other properties
)
```

Comment: Actually issue when I tring the context it popping all the '/booking/hotelDetail' and also an another page ('/listing') too. this context always giving current route name '/booking/hotelDetail' even if it is '/listing'. so listing page also popping.

Comment: if(ModalRoute.of(context)! .settings .name == '/booking/hotelDetail' && Navigator.of(context).canPop()) { Navigator.of(context).pop(); }. (not working this)

Comment: from your answer, I don't know why we use `navigatorKey`, just use BuildContext